# Magento shop, how to modify list view when user use mobile for visiting my webshop?

Tags: magento

I need to know how to modify the catalog file in such a way that it only shows me the product catalog as a list and not as a grid when the user uses a mobile. But only when user use mobile for visiting my magento shop
Which file DO I have to modify and how?
Thanks a lot for help

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to check if UA is mobile (with [Best way to detect mobile users in Magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9062166/best-way-to-detect-mobile-users-in-magento) or similar way).
2. Then force switch store view to your optimized for mobile view template
3. Next go in backend `System => Configuration => Catalog => Catalog => Frontend` and set `List Mode => List only`

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by css.You can see the bootstrap framework for responsive view.This can be used to detect the screen resolution and can render the view according to the screen size.